# List files Ids from google drive as array in CentOS VPS

Tags: shell, centos

I'm runing this command: drive list -n the output I get is this :

```
0B8_ubsKKwerXY............   dump-2016-09-01_04-00-01.sql   99.5 MB   2016-09-01 04:00:30
0B8_ubsKKwer..............   dump-2016-08-31_04-00-01.sql  97.8 MB   2016-08-31 04:00:16
```

I tried to capture the result and put it in an array so I can extract only the ID and dates by creating an script shell file and inserting the below 2 lines :

```
#test.sh file
mapfile -t array < <(drive list -n) 
echo $array
```

however when running my script via `./test.sh` I get only the first line as `output 0B8_ubsKKwerXY............   dump-2016-09-01_04-00-01.sql   99.5 MB   2016-09-01 04:00:30`
and not in an array at all so what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Please update a verifiable sample i/p and expected o/p!

Comment: What I expect is an array of data with the following values  $arry[0] = 0B8_ubsKKwerXY............  $arra[1] = dump-2016-09-01_04-00-01.sql, $arra[2] = 99.5 MB, $array[3] = 2016-09-01 array[4] = 04:00:30

Comment: Where will the entries of the next line go, the one with the id `0B8_ubsKKwer..............`?

Comment: I want an array that holds each row as an array so this  $arry[0] = 0B8_ubsKKwerXY............ $arra[1] = dump-2016-09-01_04-00-01.sql, $arra[2] = 99.5 MB, $array[3] = 2016-09-01 array[4] = 04:00:30 sould be first array in the global array